# Cisco pix 515e vpn logs

Tags: cisco-vpn

How do i find list of users that logged into the cisco VPN during particular duration from the cli.

i am looking for vpn logs for particular duration because my log server was crashed.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of this question... you're looking for information in the logs, but your log server crashed?  How do you think you'll find this information, without logs?

Answer (score 0):

The pix 515e only keeps a small amount of log content locally, so if you manange to keep your logs clean it might still be in the buffer, and this relies on you having not disabled logging buffered.

if the information is in the log on the box you will need to use regex to grab the required items.

something like this might work

show log | i ((Group = .*). (Username = .*) (authenticated.)

I use the above on an ASA so i dont know if the that regex will work on a pix